# Sqlite update query with table shotcuts

Tags: sqlite

I am getting problem for UPDATE query in sqlite .

```
 UPDATE Table1 T1, Table2 T2 SET T1.USE_MHE = T2.USE_MHE WHERE T1.EQ_NAME= T2.EQ_NAME
```

Above query works fine for MS access ADO connection. 
But for SQLite it's looks like using table shortcut is not possible (Table1 T1) I have 100's of such query to update. Please let me know how table shortcut can be used in SQLite update query.,

Comment: Add 'as' keyword between full name and shortcut

Comment: @  moonlight : using "as" also does not solves issue. giving error for as

Comment: @Sandip, what is the error you're getting?

Comment: @ evilone: Error "error near 'T1'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not aliases that you're using. Your UPDATE clause is wrong. Try:

```
UPDATE 
   Table1 AS T1 
SET 
   T1.USE_MHE = (SELECT T2.USE_MHE FROM Table2 AS T2 WHERE T1.EQ_NAME = T2.EQ_NAME)
WHERE
   EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table2 AS T2 WHERE T1.EQ_NAME = T2.EQ_NAME);
```

Comment: @ evilone: Two where is typo. there is only one where

Comment: That's spot on. The table being updated is the only one to say after update.